# Change WebView URL on button tap

Tags: java, android, webview

I want when someone tap a button to change URL WebView used.

First time, app shows yahoo.com. This is correct.
When someone tap first or second button, links are opened in browser. What I have to do to "refresh" the page? Hope you understand.

Here is my .xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="buttonClick"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

        Context context = this;
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(context.getFilesDir().getPath());

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com");

    }

    public void buttonClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://bing.com");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the result you get now and what do you want?

Comment: When someone tap first or second button, links are opened in (external) browser. I just want to show links in my WebView (`activity_main_webview`).

Comment: check my answer, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`loadUrl` is opening a new browser because you reset the layout, resulting in a new webview object without `webviewclient`.

Remove the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Lines and also the re-initiation of the webview.
You will get:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://bing.com");
                break;
        }
    }
```